# А как добавить апплет показывающий температуру процессора в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Собственно вопрос в сабже. 
Поставил sensor-applet но как его запустить не могу понять.
В интернете поискал - описывается как ткнуть в панель правой кнопкой мыши и выскочит контекстное меню где будет возможность добавления апплетов на панель - но у меня не какой реакции на нажатие правой кнопкой мыши нет...

Comment: вы уверены, что sensor-applet может работать на Unity (вместо GNOME)?

Comment: @jfs нет. Я Недавно на убунту с кубунту перешел и пока изучаю это дело...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас уже стоит `lm-sensors` (`sensors` в командной строке нужную информацию показывает), можно [`psensors` поставить](https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/):

```
$ sudo apt-get install psensor
```

Comment: Сегодня вечером попробую. Заранее спасибо!