# Как на Python 3 получить информацию о температуре процессора?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как узнать температуру процессора? Какие есть библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [этим](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspectator/). А вообще в гугле полно ответов.

```
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
from time import sleep
cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
with cpu:
    for _ in range(8):
       cpu.load, cpu.temperature
       sleep(1.1)
```

Comment: спасибо! я установил модуль pyspectator , но он требует модуль win32com , который через pip не устанавливается , что посоветуете?

Comment: pip install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl Для версии 2.7, если не ваша версия, измените 27 на нужную вам. А также разрядность системы

Comment: Установил....)  теперь  win32com требует  win32api , он тоже не ставится через pip ... как быть ?

Comment: у меня питон 3.5.2

Comment: в pywin должно всё быть. Попробуйте установить отсюда https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

Comment: Alban можно ещё вопрос вы скачивали файлы с этого сайта  sourceforge.net , у меня не получается меня постояно выкидывает на одну и туже страницу ?

Comment: Вот держите, для python 3.5x https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/pywin32-220.win32-py3.5.exe/download

Answer (score 3):

Есть хорошая [библиотека](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspectator/), установить можно через pip.

Пример кода:

```
from pyspectator import Cpu
from time import sleep
cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)

while True:
    print cpu.temperature
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

На Linux, есть [`psutil.sensors_temperatures()`](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.sensors_temperatures):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()
{'acpitz': [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=103.0, critical=103.0)],
 'asus': [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=None, critical=None)],
 'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Physical id 0', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
              shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=47.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0)]}
```

Можно значения, возвращаемые `sensors_temperatures()` вызовом, сравнить с тем, что [psensor показывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621405/23044).

[`psutil` широко используется](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#summary).

Comment: Не знал об этом. Как всегда на высоте)