# Python: измерение температуры CPU с помощью pyspectator

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu

Пользуясь официальной документацией, попытался измерить температуру CPU, на что получаю ответ None

```
>>> from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
>>> cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
>>> print(cpu.temperature)
None
```

Необходимые пакеты установлены: psutil, netifaces, enum34.
Совершенно не понимаю почему такой странный вывод, ведь по идее эта либа частично основана на psutil, с помощью которой мне удалось (не самый удобный способ) измерить температуру CPU.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как на Python 3 получить информацию о температуре процессора?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/635476/23044)

Comment: Да, видел этот вопрос, пробовал, но ошибка осталась

Comment: код с psutil работает.

Comment: Да, и я это в вопросе говорил. Но способ не самый удобный, поэтому хочется понять проблему с pyspectator

Comment: я говорю что [ответ с psutil работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635732/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ждать более чем `monitoring_latency`. Используйте например

```
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
from time import sleep

cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
with cpu:
    for __ in range(4):
        print(cpu.temperature)
        sleep(1.1)
```

Comment: В итоге я получаю четыре раза вывод None (менял range, без изменений)

Comment: Может быть, что ваш хардвер не выдает информации о температуре процессора.

Answer (score 0):

Необходим запуск с повышенными правами, исполните скрипт от имени администратора.